# Which control add in Master Page to define region?

Tags: .net, asp.net, webforms, master-pages, contentplaceholder

I am developing an ASP.NET Web application. I create a master page. The master page requires a region where i can add page-specific content by using the ASP.NET page designer. I need to add a control to the master page to define the region. Which control should I add?

**ContentPlaceHolder** or **PlaceHolder**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ContentPlaceHolder` is specifically for use on master pages to hold page-specific content.  `PlaceHolder` is for use on content pages.

Use `ContentPlaceHolder`.

Comment: Exactly, but guest what. Training for my 70-515 certification, I found a question that say that correct answer is PlaceHolder. `You are developing an ASP.NET Web application. You create a master page. The master page requires a region where you can add page-specific content by using the ASP.NET page designer. You need to add a control to the master page to define the region. Which control should you add?`